# How to get fields in a csv file to line up with one another programmatically

Tags: python, csv, data-cleaning

I have a very old set of data that I am working on cleaning. I have gotten it put into a csv file but the data is not consistent line to line. I would to get each field in each line to match up to others in lines before or after it.

```
data = """
30,1204,PO,71100,147130,I09,B10,OC,350,20105402
31,1221,PO,70400,147170,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
32,1223,SI,70384,147122,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,3,BO,OI,20105402
33,1224,SI,70392,147032,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105402
34,1227,PO,70400,146430,I09,B10,PF,500,20105402
35,1241,PO,71100,146420,I09,B10,PF,500,20105402
36,1249,PO,71100,146000,I09,B10,SN,500,20105402
37,1305,PO,70400,146000,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
38,1307,SI,70379,146041,I09,B10,OC,500,21,BH,1,BO,195,40,SW,20105402
39,1312,SD,70372,146062,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
40,1332,SI,70334,146309,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,4,BO,OI,20105402
41,1332,SI,70334,146309,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,5,BO,OI,20105403
42,1333,SI,70333,146324,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,2,BO,OI,20105403
43,1334,SI,70328,146348,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
44,1335,SI,70326,146356,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
45,1336,SI,70310,146424,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
46,1338,SI,70302,146457,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
47,1338,SI,70301,146464,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
48,1340,SI,70295,146503,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,8,BO,OI,20105403
49,1405,LD,2,70119,148280,I10,B10,OC,0000,20105403
01,1024,LA,1R,70120,148280,B10,OC,0000,21105501
02,1039,PO,70340,149400,I10,B10,OC,500,21105501
03,1045,SI,70378,149025,I10,B07,PF,300,PN,17,BO,OI,21105501
"""
```

Here is an example of what the data looks like. As you can see some lines are the same length while others are of different lengths. Some fields are consistent line to line when the lines are the same length but when the lines are different lengths the fields are in different places.

I am really just looking for some ideas of how to go about cleaning this in python so that I can get as many of the fields lined up as possible and actually be able to use this data.

Comment: There is no chance. Look upstream to what writes the data

Comment: As a human reading the data, do you have a way to tell which field each value is supposed to correspond to?

Comment: Fix what generated the inconsistent data

Answer (score 0):

One of the things you might want to consider doing is understanding what the extra data is for.

You could start by adding headers to your csv file.  That will help with the mapping of fields.  If you don't need that data, you can always add some sort of line in your that as the reader in `csv.reader` looks at a line, and see's that extra data, to remove it or move to the end of the line and you place your header for that data at the end of the line as well.

For example:

```
30,1204,PO,71100,147130,I09,B10,OC,350,20105402
31,1221,PO,70400,147170,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
32,1223,SI,70384,147122,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,3,BO,OI,20105402
33,1224,SI,70392,147032,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105402
```

we see here that lines 3 and 4 have some extra.  Again, I don't know what any of this data is for, but from the looks of it, it all pretty much lines up except for when the extra data is there.

in your python code you could write something like...

```py
import csv
import re


cleaned_data = []


reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter=',')


for row in reader:

    if len(row) >= 10 and not re.match(r'\d{8}', row[9]):

        for i, element in enumerate(row):
            if re.match(r'\d{8}', element):
                row[9], row[i] = row[i], row[9]
                del row[i+1:]
                break


    cleaned_data.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without context what each column means is for us impossible to make some definitive answer. Here is how you can start: split each row to according the `,` and make dataframes according number of items in each row.

Then you can further clean your data based on your needs:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

data = """
30,1204,PO,71100,147130,I09,B10,OC,350,20105402
31,1221,PO,70400,147170,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
32,1223,SI,70384,147122,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,3,BO,OI,20105402
33,1224,SI,70392,147032,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105402
34,1227,PO,70400,146430,I09,B10,PF,500,20105402
35,1241,PO,71100,146420,I09,B10,PF,500,20105402
36,1249,PO,71100,146000,I09,B10,SN,500,20105402
37,1305,PO,70400,146000,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
38,1307,SI,70379,146041,I09,B10,OC,500,21,BH,1,BO,195,40,SW,20105402
39,1312,SD,70372,146062,I09,B10,OC,500,20105402
40,1332,SI,70334,146309,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,4,BO,OI,20105402
41,1332,SI,70334,146309,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,5,BO,OI,20105403
42,1333,SI,70333,146324,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,2,BO,OI,20105403
43,1334,SI,70328,146348,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
44,1335,SI,70326,146356,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
45,1336,SI,70310,146424,I09,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
46,1338,SI,70302,146457,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
47,1338,SI,70301,146464,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,1,BO,OI,20105403
48,1340,SI,70295,146503,I10,B10,OC,500,PN,8,BO,OI,20105403
49,1405,LD,2,70119,148280,I10,B10,OC,0000,20105403
01,1024,LA,1R,70120,148280,B10,OC,0000,21105501
02,1039,PO,70340,149400,I10,B10,OC,500,21105501
03,1045,SI,70378,149025,I10,B07,PF,300,PN,17,BO,OI,21105501
"""

all_data = {}
for line in map(str.strip, data.splitlines()):
    if line == "":
        continue
    line = line.split(",")
    all_data.setdefault(len(line), []).append(line)


for v in all_data.values():
    df = pd.DataFrame(v)
    print(df)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
    0     1   2      3       4       5    6   7     8         9
0  30  1204  PO  71100  147130     I09  B10  OC   350  20105402
1  31  1221  PO  70400  147170     I09  B10  OC   500  20105402
2  34  1227  PO  70400  146430     I09  B10  PF   500  20105402
3  35  1241  PO  71100  146420     I09  B10  PF   500  20105402
4  36  1249  PO  71100  146000     I09  B10  SN   500  20105402
5  37  1305  PO  70400  146000     I09  B10  OC   500  20105402
6  39  1312  SD  70372  146062     I09  B10  OC   500  20105402
7  01  1024  LA     1R   70120  148280  B10  OC  0000  21105501
8  02  1039  PO  70340  149400     I10  B10  OC   500  21105501
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0     1   2      3       4    5    6   7    8   9   10  11  12        13
0   32  1223  SI  70384  147122  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   3  BO  OI  20105402
1   33  1224  SI  70392  147032  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105402
2   40  1332  SI  70334  146309  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   4  BO  OI  20105402
3   41  1332  SI  70334  146309  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   5  BO  OI  20105403
4   42  1333  SI  70333  146324  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   2  BO  OI  20105403
5   43  1334  SI  70328  146348  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105403
6   44  1335  SI  70326  146356  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105403
7   45  1336  SI  70310  146424  I09  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105403
8   46  1338  SI  70302  146457  I10  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105403
9   47  1338  SI  70301  146464  I10  B10  OC  500  PN   1  BO  OI  20105403
10  48  1340  SI  70295  146503  I10  B10  OC  500  PN   8  BO  OI  20105403
11  03  1045  SI  70378  149025  I10  B07  PF  300  PN  17  BO  OI  21105501
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0     1   2      3       4    5    6   7    8   9   10 11  12   13  14  15        16
0  38  1307  SI  70379  146041  I09  B10  OC  500  21  BH  1  BO  195  40  SW  20105402
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   0     1   2  3      4       5    6    7   8     9         10
0  49  1405  LD  2  70119  148280  I10  B10  OC  0000  20105403
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is _so much_ wrong with this. Are you happy with the output?

Comment: @roganjosh There is not enough info (what each column means). User has to analyze each dataframe and insert/remove columns by himself.

Comment: Where have you asked for the extra info? You answered, said there wasn't enough info, but never actually checked for it.

Comment: @roganjosh For example first dataframe has 10 columns, second dataframe has 14 columns - so user must add extra columns to first dataframe or remove columns from second dataframe (That I don't know how to answer by myself)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're asking for is just a way to line up the columns visually.  Once you can see it, hopefully you'll have enough to see which columns are missing and which are surplus.

```
col_width = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    cols = line.split(',')
    for i, item in enumerate(cols):
        if i < len(col_width):
            col_width[i] = max(col_width[i], len(item))
        else:
            col_width.append(len(item))

for line in data.split('\n'):
    cols = line.split(',')
    new_cols = []
    for item, width in zip(cols, col_width):
        padding = ' ' * (width - len(item))
        new_cols.append(padding + item)
    print(','.join(new_cols))
  
30,1204,PO,71100,147130,   I09,B10, OC, 350,20105402
31,1221,PO,70400,147170,   I09,B10, OC, 500,20105402
32,1223,SI,70384,147122,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       3,BO,OI,20105402
33,1224,SI,70392,147032,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105402
34,1227,PO,70400,146430,   I09,B10, PF, 500,20105402
35,1241,PO,71100,146420,   I09,B10, PF, 500,20105402
36,1249,PO,71100,146000,   I09,B10, SN, 500,20105402
37,1305,PO,70400,146000,   I09,B10, OC, 500,20105402
38,1307,SI,70379,146041,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      21,      BH, 1,BO,     195,40,SW,20105402
39,1312,SD,70372,146062,   I09,B10, OC, 500,20105402
40,1332,SI,70334,146309,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       4,BO,OI,20105402
41,1332,SI,70334,146309,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       5,BO,OI,20105403
42,1333,SI,70333,146324,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       2,BO,OI,20105403
43,1334,SI,70328,146348,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105403
44,1335,SI,70326,146356,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105403
45,1336,SI,70310,146424,   I09,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105403
46,1338,SI,70302,146457,   I10,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105403
47,1338,SI,70301,146464,   I10,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       1,BO,OI,20105403
48,1340,SI,70295,146503,   I10,B10, OC, 500,      PN,       8,BO,OI,20105403
49,1405,LD,    2, 70119,148280,I10,B10,  OC,    0000,20105403
01,1024,LA,   1R, 70120,148280,B10, OC,0000,21105501
02,1039,PO,70340,149400,   I10,B10, OC, 500,21105501
03,1045,SI,70378,149025,   I10,B07, PF, 300,      PN,      17,BO,OI,21105501
```